# Python - Reduce executable size

Tags: python, size, exe

My Actual exe size its 14MB, Im using auto-py-to-exe for convert it to exe.
There are another option for reduce it?
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked up how to reduce the size of .exe files in general? For instance have you tried using an EXE packer? Or is this your first step for researching the issue? StackOverflow should be a last resort, not the first place you come to. If you've done research beforehand please tell us what you've done, so we don't have to necessarily re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

This is roughly the size of the Python interpreter itself. You will not be able to reduce it much more.

You may want to check other similar solutions such as cx_Freeze, or another option, Nuitka.